# Normalizers in linear algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group (say, over an algebraically closed field) and let $H < G$ be a closed connected subgroup.  Let $N_G(H)$ be the normalizer of $H$ in $G$, and assume that $N_G(H)=H$.  Does there necessarily exist a single element $h \in H$ such that if $g \in G$ satisfies $g h g^{-1} \in H$, then $g \in H$?

In the setting I am in $H$ is solvable, but I doubt that is relevant to the question.

Comment: "Say, over an algebraically closed field" is not just an aside—it's essential!  Otherwise, this does not work if $H$ is a maximal split torus in $G = \operatorname{SL}_2$ over $\mathbb F_2$.  I do not know a general result of the sort you seek, but is it possible that you know more about $H$, for example, that it is a Borel subgroup of $G$?

Comment: If $H$ is reductive, you take a regular element $h$. Then $H$ is the Zariski closure of the group generated by all $H$-conjugates of $h$. Then the claim follows.

Comment: @Echo, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453342/normalizers-in-linear-algebraic-groups#comment1172809_453342), how does the claim follow?  I don't see why $g h g^{-1} \in H$ implies that the $g$-conjugate of every $H$-conjugate of $h$ lies in $H$ (or maybe that wasn't your point).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was too optimistic. If $H$ is a torus, it works, otherwise it doesn't.